# Getting key from values present in a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary of dictionaries, like given below:

```
{
   "dev": {
      "project_id": "dev_project_id",
      "secret_id": "dev_secret_id",
      "secret_project_id": "dev_secret_project_id",
      "service_account_email": "dev_service_account_email@gmail.com",
      "email_list": ["dev_email@gmail.com"],
      "core_func_path":"dev/core_func.py",
      "secret_id_email": "dev_secret_id_email"
   },
   "prod": {
      "project_id": "prod_project_id",
      "secret_id": "prod_secret_id",
      "secret_project_id": "prod_secret_project_id",
      "service_account_email": "prod_service_account_email@gmail.com",
      "email_list": ["prod_email_list@gmail.com"],
      "core_func_path":"prod/core_func.py",
      "secret_id_email": "prod_secret_id_email"
   }
}
```

And I need to extract key when a specific project_id is provided.

Till now, I have this code, which can get values from a dictionary, however, it is failing for a dictionary of dictionaries.

```
check_project_id='dev_project_id'    
curr_dir = Path(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    default_config_dir = os.fspath(Path(curr_dir.parent.parent, 'config').resolve())
    constants_path = str(default_config_dir)+'/config.json'
    with open(constants_path, 'r') as f:
        std_config = json.load(f)
        for val in std_config.values():
            if(val['project_id']==check_project_id):
                print(list(std_config.keys())[list(std_config.values()).index(check_project_id)])
```

Is there any way I can implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, `std_config` is your dictionary of dictionaries. Just use the `items` call on the dictionary to be able to extract the key that matches your criteria.

```
for k, v in std_config.items():
    if v["project_id"] == check_project_id:
        print(k)

> dev
```